# how to select all controls in .net/c# like $('*') in jQuery?

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering if there is a way to select all controls/items in asp.net/c# like $('*') performed in jQuery

Comment: Depends what technology you're using. Winforms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? MonoTouch?

Comment: probably not ;-)  but it might help to know if you talking about winforms, wpf, asp.net, asp.net mvc, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allCtrls = GetChildren(Page);

protected IEnumerable<Control> GetChildren(Control parent)
{   
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return ctrl;
        foreach (Control ctrl2 in GetChildren(ctrl))
            yield return ctrl2;
    }
}
```